# Book recommendation: which one is better optimization textbook?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, book-recommendation, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am a student taking a course on optimization and we have a selection of three textbooks (in no particular order):

1. Numerical Optimization by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen Wright, Springer Verlag; second edition
2. Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe, Cambridge University Press
3. Nonlinear Programming by Dimitri P. Bertsekas, Athena Scientific; 2nd edition

Can anyone recommend one of these textbooks as a primary reference? Preferably, the textbook is up-to-date with the current literature and "hot" research areas in optimization.

Comment: All are good, #2 is most recent but is focused mainly on convex (& related) problems (a hot topic). If you are dealing with optimization in general (not just convex), both #1,#3 are solid texts.

Comment: Check out the two recent SIAM books by Amir Beck which I like even better.

Comment: @max_zorn Thanks for mentioning those new books by Beck, I didn't know about them. They look very good. Do you have any other favorite optimization books or books on related topics that you feel like recommending? What are your favorite convex analysis books?

Comment: Hi @littleO, to be clear all the above books are good it comes down to personal preference at the end. I also like of course Rockafellar's old but still fantastic *Convex Analysis*, Rockafellar and Wets' *Variational Analysis*. For teaching/selfstudy, Mordukhovich and Nam's *An easy path to convex analysis and optimization* is nice. For research, Mordukhovich, Bauschke-Combettes, Simons (for monotone operators), and I fear I forgot a few good ones.

Comment: The books that you've mentioned cover very different material.  Your choice will depend on what you're most interested in and what you have to study in this course.

Comment: @max_zorn Thanks. I assume the book by Simon you're referring to is [Convexity: An Analytic Viewpoint](https://www.amazon.com/Convexity-Analytic-Viewpoint-Cambridge-Mathematics/dp/1107007313).

Comment: @littleO: No, actually I mean Stephen Simons' Springer books. These are not for the faint-hearted but has nice material on the Brezis-Haraux theorem and other goodies.

Comment: @max_zorn Gotcha, thanks. Looks good.